# Cython: exception type for a function returning a typed memoryview

Tags: exception, cython, typed-memory-views

In a `cdef` signature of a function:

```
cdef const unsigned char[:, :] my_fn(input) except <????> :
```

What shall I put in `<????>`?

If I understand the [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values) correctly, specifying an exception type is necessary for exception to propagate up the Python stack.

I tried things as `[b'\x00']` and empty Cython arrays, none works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news: You can't do it. Good news: You don't have to do it!

The syntax with `except <xxx>` is only possible if the `cdef` function returns an `int`, an enum, a float or a pointer - basically something for which it makes sense to compare via `==` in C.

A typed memory view is a Python-object, which has a built-in way to signal an error - when the returned object is a null-pointer. Thus, you don't have to define an exceptional value because it is already defined!

For example:

```
%%cython
cdef int[:] worker(int[:] memview, int index):
    memview[index]=10 
    return memview

def runit(index):
    cdef int mem[4]
    print(worker(mem,index))
```

And now

```
runit(4)   #4 -> out of bounds
print("I still run")
```

doesn't print "I still run" because the out-of-bounds exception is propagated.

This would not be the case for a return value, which is not a Python object, for example an `int`:

```
%%cython
cdef int worker(int[:] memview, int index):
    return memview[index]
```

And now:

```
runit(4)   #4 -> out of bounds
print("I still run")
```

prints "0" and "I still run", because the error is not propagated. We can choose an exceptional value, for example `-1` so the error is propagated via return-value=-1:

```
%%cython
cdef int worker(int[:] memview, int index) except -1:
    return memview[index]
```

Now, "I still run" is no longer printed.

However, sometimes there is no good exceptional value, for example because `memview` could contain any integer value:

```
%%cython
cdef int worker(int[:] memview, int index) except -1:
    return memview[index]

def runit(index):
    cdef int mem[4]
    mem[0]=-1
    print(worker(mem, index))
```

Now, running

```
runit(0)
print("I still run")
```

ends in a spurious error:

> SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error

The solution is to use

```
cdef int worker(int[:] memview, int index) except *
```

which has the right behavior for `runit(0)` and `runit(4)`.

So what are the costs of using `except *` compared to `except -1`? They are not really high:

If the returned value is `-1` (this is the default "exceptional" value), then we know that an error could have happened (it is only a possibility not a certainty) and check via `PyErr_Occurred()`, whether it is really the case.

As @DavidW mentioned in the comment, it is also possible to use `except? -1` which has the advantage that it is easier to read and to understand. The funny thing is, that this would produce the same C-code as `except *`, because the default error-value is `-1`!

However, the `except?`-syntax allows us to choose the function result for which we have to pay the overhead of `PyErr_Occurred()`. If for example, we would know, that the result `-1` occurs pretty often and `-2` almost never, so we could use `except? -2` and `PyErr_Occured()` would be checked only if the result of the function is `-2`, that means almost never (in the case of `except *` it would be checked pretty often - every time `-1` is returned).

Comment: Or  `except? -1` to indicate that -1 could be an error (but isn't necessaril)

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the hint! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to pass in what's now the return value by reference and instead return an int which signals error codes.